# jquery run instruction from html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

is a php code that has a loop this loop creates buttons dynamically. when I click on any of the buttons it should be disabled. for this I use the jquery that is in question, want to know how the jquery will know which button he needs disable

```
$nomecampoliga=1 or2, or 3, is dynamics.


<html>
<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_BOTH)){

echo "<input type='submit' class='<?php $nomecampoliga; ?>' name=$on value='Liga'>";
?>
```

when I click the button above, the follow code runs

Now my question how the follow Jquery can get $name dynamic value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(".??????").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Add another static class or an ID

Comment: the html button is inside a loop

Comment: please write your question better, I have no idea what you're talking about. Do you need the javascript to have your PHP variable inside it when it's ran?

Comment: I explained better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common class

```
echo '<input type="submit" class="'.$nomecampoliga.' buttons" name="'.$on.'" value="Liga">';
```

target that class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now the jquery works fine, but now other part of code stop.

Comment: I have this code, it call the php function liga(). runs if the $on exist, but after your code no more run.
   if (isset($_POST[$on])) {//
    unset($_POST[$on]);//
    liga();

Comment: I'm not sure what `$on` is, I assumed it was a PHP variable due to the missing quotes and the dollarsign? If it's the actual name of the element, you have to remove the quotes and periods.

Comment: $on is a php variable. can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: If it's a variable, it should work just the way it is. Try dumping the $_POST variable and see what you've got.